# Guide to use Restlet Swagger extension for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet, swagger, swagger-ui

I tried to do a similar approach:

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router apiRouter = createApiRouter();
        attachSwaggerSpecificationRestlet(apiRouter, "/api-docs");
        return apiRouter;
}
```

When `/api-docs` is access Restlet throws Error 404, what could be messing. The idea is that the apiRouter we have is fully working at this state, when we acess resource like `/stuff` etc.

What could be missing in this code? Or is there any specific notes to take into consideration when using Restlet Swagger extension for GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your usecase and I can make work the Swagger extension with the following Maven configuration (`restlet-version` = 2.3.1)AE dev server:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.swagger</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.raml</groupId>
                <artifactId>raml-parser</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can notice that I had to exclude the RAML parser within the `ext.swagger`.

Here is the code of my Restlet application:

```
public class RestletApplication extends SwaggerApplication {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        router.attach("/ping", MyServerResource.class);
        attachSwaggerSpecificationRestlet(router, "/docs");

        return router;
    }
}
```

If it can help you, I can provide my test project within a Github repository.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Is the "org.restlet.ext.jetty" necessary?

Comment: No sorry. I added it to be able to test in a servlet container and in a GAE mode to be sure that the problem wasn't related to GAE only. I just made a test without the extension `ext.jetty` and it still works...

Comment: You also have this error within the gae dev server? Do you have other dependencies in your project (xstream, ...)? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of GAE do you use?

Comment: I'm using GAE version 1.9.18, I checked the logs and saw more errors: http://pastekit.com/k5okRN   and yes XStream was used in the dependency why?

Comment: Hi Thierry, would there be any issue I we use XStream in the dependency? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Your last stacktrace let me think that there is a conflict between two versions of Jackson (one from the extension swagger and one from a dependency of your application)...

Comment: Which jackson dependency should be used?

Comment: Are you sure to exclude Jackson from all other dependencies? The extension swagger uses version 2.2.4 (it's what I have within my project) in my case...

Comment: I see, this is the only visible jackson dependency in the POM: http://pastekit.com/jRgrkR

Comment: Aha! I works now. Nice. I replaced the Jackson version to 2.2.4 cool. This should be added to the Restlet Swagger Readme I guess. :-)

Comment: Agreed! I'll add an issue for this in the Restlet repository ;-) Thanks very much for reporting this!

Comment: Added issue: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1046. Thanks very much for reporting this ;-)

Comment: Cool. I have checked the issue. BTW, here's a follow up question perhaps you might know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342625/is-there-a-way-to-make-restlet-swagger-extension-limit-the-api-it-shows