# Guide to use Swagger UI for Restlet GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet, swagger, swagger-ui

So far I was able to run Swagger for GAE with this QA: [Guide to use Restlet Swagger extension for GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319076/guide-to-use-restlet-swagger-extension-for-gae)

Now I want to know if there is a guide will show how to integrate Swagger-UI with Restlet GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to `git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist`

and copy the `dist` content into the WAR directory, then accessing `index.html` will show the Swagger UI then input the path of the `/api-docs` or `/docs` that was defined in through `attachSwaggerSpecificationRestlet` See: [Guide to use Restlet Swagger extension for GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319076/guide-to-use-restlet-swagger-extension-for-gae) for details.