# Is there a way to make Restlet Swagger extension limit the API it shows?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet, swagger

Is there a way to make Restlet Swagger extension limit the API it shows?

There are paths in the API we have that should not be explosed (just yet), what is the strategy to make sure that at least only specific `org.restlet.routing.Router` will  be exposed? As we have many `Router`s in the Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible out of the box. The easier way to do that is IMO to patch the extension `org.restlet.extension.swagger`:

- Update the method `getSwagger` of the class `SwaggerSpecificationRestlet` to allow to update introspected definition filtering, as described below:

  ```
  public Representation getSwagger() {
      Definition definition = getDefinition();
      // The method to add for filtering the instropected structure
      filterDefinition(definition);
      Swagger swagger = Swagger2Translator.getSwagger(definition);
      (...)
  }

  protected void filterDefinition(Definition definition) {
  }
  ```
- In your application, configure this class by overriding the method `getSwaggerSpecificationRestlet`:

  ```
  public SwaggerSpecificationRestlet getSwaggerSpecificationRestlet(
                   Context context) {
      SwaggerSpecificationRestlet result
                 = new SwaggerSpecificationRestlet(this) {
          protected void filterDefinition(Definition definition) {
              (...)
          }
      };
      result.setApiInboundRoot(this);
      return result;
  }
  ```

Here is a sample of the method `filterDefinition`:

```
private Definition filterDefinition(Definition definition) {
    List<Resource> resourcesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    Contract contract = definition.getContract();
    for (Resource resource : contract.getResources()) {
        resourcesToRemove.add(resource);
    }

    for (Resource resource : resourcesToRemove) {
        contract.getResources().remove(resource);
    }

    return definition;
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: There's no getSwagger() method in the SwaggerSpecificationRestlet class? Version 2.3.1

Comment: I tried adding logs in my code and the only one that gets triggered is the getSwaggerSpecificationRestlet() method and not the filterDefinition() see http://www.pastekit.com/n5l5DD    this is because the getSwagger() is not overridden? However I can't find that method...